# this.state.json.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, frontend

I have a problem displaying JSON data. I have a class that returns an array of objects with JSON data. I import this class in another one and try to map through its return (array of JSON objects) but it does not seem to work.

It fails with the error:

> TypeError: this.state.json.map is not a function

Here is the code

**Contact.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Contact extends Component {
render () {
    return  [
        {
            "name" : "Alex",
            "number" : "088217821878",
        },
        {
            "name" : "Rosie",
            "number" : "087627627132",
        }
    ];
}
}
```

**List.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Contact from './Contact';


class List extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        json: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
            json: Contact
        }
    })
}
render() {
  return (
      <div>
        <table class="table is-bordered is-hoverable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {this.state.json.map((data, i) => {
                return (
                    <tr key={i}>
                        <td>{data.name}</td>
                        <td>{data.number}</td>               
                    </tr>
                )
            })}                       
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </div> 

    );
}
}

export default List;
```

Comment: there's no error in visual code and command line but it is in browser. it displays TypeError: this.state.json.map is not a function

Comment: You are setting your json variable to reference the whole Contact component...

Comment: You shouldn't really use a component to return JSON like that. You should just be able to require/import the json.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you mix data and visual component.

I guess at first that you don't need Contact  list in state in List.js.

So my suggestion is pass contact data into List.js as props.

So define contact data as const or if you use state machine like Redux create store for that.

**Contact.js**

```
    export const Contacts =[
        {
            "name" : "Alex",
            "number" : "088217821878",
        },
        {
            "name" : "Rosie",
            "number" : "087627627132",
        }
    ];
```

**List.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';   


class List extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table class="table is-bordered is-hoverable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {this.props.contacts.map((data, i) => {
                return (
                    <tr key={i}>
                        <td>{data.name}</td>
                        <td>{data.number}</td>               
                    </tr>
                )
            })}                       
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </div> 

    );
  }
}

export default List;
```

Than in parent component use it as

```
import { Contacts } from './Contact';
```

and in render method use

```
<List
contacts={Contacts}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really use a component to return JSON like that, so here's another way to approach it.

Have the contacts JSON as a file stored locally:

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "name": "Alex",
      "number": "088217821878"
    },
    {
      "name": "Rosie",
      "number": "087627627132"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you should just be able to import the contacts straight into the list component and store it in your state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { contacts } from './contacts.json';

class List extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { contacts }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table class="table is-bordered is-hoverable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.contacts.map((data, i) => {
              return (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td>{data.name}</td>
                  <td>{data.number}</td>               
                </tr>
              )
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default List;
```

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/j25hfgy2/1/)**

As @Ivan Mjartan suggests, however, you might want to consider importing the contact list in the parent component, and passing the array down down to `List` as a property.

```
<List contacts={contacts} />
```

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/fjrp6jLe/1/)**